# How to specify to which account GoogleCl youtube uploads?

Tags: youtube, googlecl

I have a couple youtube accounts connected to my Google account, I tried using googlecl to upload a video from my home server and obviously it uploaded my private video to organisation account I have access to. It just asks me for my username, not for account name. Tried googling, found nothing.